# Represent try..catch without exception variable or filter using expression tree factory methods

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Which factory method in `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` should I call to create an expression tree -- more specifically, a `CatchBlock` instance -- which represents the `catch` in the following C# code:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch {
    // ...
}
```

[All the overloads of the **Catch** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.catch) seem to require either an exception type -- the equivalent of this:

```
catch (Exception) {
    // ...
}
```

and/or a `ParameterExpression` which will be bound to the exception -- the equivalent of this:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    // ...
}
```

Passing `null` into the first argument (and casting to `Type` to avoid ambiguity):

```
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Catch((Type)null, Constant(true));
```

causes an **ArgumentNullException**.

The [**MakeCatchBlock** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.makecatchblock) has the same behavior

Comment: What would you catch if not a `System.Exception`?

Comment: AFAIK (and according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8901166/3094533) as well), `try {...} catch {...}` is equivalent to `try {...} catch(Exception) {...}` - so you can simply create a `catch(Exception) {...}` expression instead of `catch {...}` expression.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It seems that a plain `catch` is a [valid way of handling non-CLS exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/how-to-catch-a-non-cls-exception), which may not inherit from `System.Exception`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/how-to-catch-a-non-cls-exception) indicates otherwise -- a plain `catch` will handle a non-CLS exception.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721520/2141621) in the link @ZoharPeled provided, suggests that behavior changed in .NET 3.0.  Also, are you hitting a 3rd party, non .NET library?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That answer has no references in support of its' claims, and the documentation page I linked to has been updated a number of times since .NET 3.0. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900991/111794) from the same question references the documentation page.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto _are you hitting a 3rd party, non .NET library_ Not quite. I've written a library which [renders expression trees as strings](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString#string-representations-of-expression-trees), and I'm writing unit tests for this scenario. But I need to create such a `CatchBlock` first.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Did you read the page you've linked to? It does not have a `try {...} catch {...}` block but a `try {...} catch(RuntimeWrappedException e) {...}` block. The `RuntimeWrappedException` class inherits `Exception` directly....

Comment: @ZoharPeled Did you read past the first bullet point? _In C# you cannot throw non-CLS exceptions, but you can catch them in two ways: ... * Within a general catch block (a catch block without an exception type specified) that is put after all other catch blocks._

Comment: Citation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimewrappedexception > .NET 2.0 onwards and since you are using LINQ, introduced in .NET 3.5, there is absolutely no way you will get problems with System.Exception

Comment: "To maintain compatibility between languages, the common language runtime (CLR) wraps objects that do not derive from Exception in a RuntimeWrappedException object.". (from the link provided by Camilo)

Comment: @ZoharPeled But C# allows you to write code that ignores any information in the exception wrapped inside the `RuntimeWrappedException` by using a plain `catch`. If it is possible to create a `CatchBlock` instance which represents this kind of code, I would like to do so and create a unit test for it.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I agree with your arguments, but you already know the answer. C# compiler cannot create expressions containing blocks, and all `Expression.Catch` methods are shortcuts for `Expression.MakeCatchBlock`, and the linked documentation states *"`type` must be non-null and match the type of variable (if it is supplied)."*. There are no other methods creating `CatchBlock` and `CatchBlock` has no public constructor.

Comment: @ZevSpitz even though `try {...} catch {...}` is valid c# that doesn't mean you can create an expression like that, and since the CLR wraps any non-CLS exception in a `RunTimeWrapperException`, it's completely equivalent to `try {...} catch(Exception e) {...}` - so I don't really understand why do you insist on it. There's a perfectly valid alternative that you can use, so why not use it?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Please write the second line of your comment (_since the CLR wraps  any non-CLS exception in a `RunTimeWrapperException`, it's completely equivalent to `try {...} catch(Exception e) {...}`_) as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `try {...} catch {...}` to catch exceptions thrown from non .Net components and therefor don't inherit from `System.Exception` is misguided since the CLR automatically wraps such exceptions with a [`RuntimeWrappedException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimewrappedexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) which obviously does inherit `System.Exception` - and therefor you can use `try {...} catch(Exception e) {...}` to catch thous exceptions as well.

Therefor, there is no need to handle the plain `try {...} catch {...}` separately from `try {...} catch (Exception e) {...}` since they both will catch all exceptions.

Comment: _there really is no point of using `try {...} catch {...}`_ -- saving an extra variable declaration? But I was thinking the answer should be, since the two are equivalent, there is no need to handle the plain `try {...} catch {...}` separately from `try {...} catch (Exception e) {...}`. see [here](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString/blob/master/Shared/CSharpCodeWriter.cs#L535).

Comment: rephrased as requested.